# PHP 7.4.3 Class in namespace returns type mismatch (TypeError) although return type is mixed

Tags: php, types, typeerror, mixed

I have just begun to use the [PHP plex-api project](https://github.com/jc21/plex-api), which has also caused me to begin using namespaces for the first time.

Now, trying to use this project without more than a few lines of documentation, I have run across an error I did not expect.

Within that project, is class Movie, which includes the following function:

```
/**
 * Method to serialize the object
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function jsonSerialize(): mixed
{
    return $this->data;
}
```

By my understanding, mixed type means, effectively, that there will be no type checking on the return value.  And yet when I call this, in this simple code:

```
$client = new PlexApi($creds['hostname']);
$client->setAuth($creds['userId'], $creds['password'] ) ;
if (true) {
    $filter1 = new Filter('title', $favoriteTitle) ;
    $librarySections = $client->getLibrarySections();
    $filter1 = new Filter('title', $favoriteTitle) ;
    foreach($librarySections['Directory'] as $directoryNumber => $directoryAttributes) {
        if ($type = $directoryAttributes['type'] != 'movie')
            continue ;
        $sectionNumber = $directoryAttributes['key'] ;
        $res = $client->filter($sectionNumber, [$filter1], true) ;
        if ($res) {
            foreach ($res as $movie) {
                $array = $movie->jsonSerialize() ;
```

That jsonSerialize() fails with the following error:

[image: Error about returning incorrect type]

This:

```
must be an instance of jc21\Movies\mixed, array returned
```

sounds like PHP is complaining that the type is incorrect for a return value that can be of any type.  What might I be missing?  This is for PHP version 7.4.3 running on Ubuntu 20.04 CLI

Looking at the detail of that message, it also seems to imply that the type 'mixed' can (should?) be defined for the namespace (jc21\Movies\mixed).  Is that correct?  How would one do that?  I have pored through a good bit of documentation about PHP and mixed type... finding nothing that seems to fit this problem.  Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

The `mixed` type was introduced with PHP 8.0.0 and thus is not available in PHP 7.4. You have to remove the return type from the function signature (but not from the docblock).

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php